# (WordPress) - How may I modify htaccess to prompt passwd with htpasswd when viewing/downloading a PDF

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I would like to ask for your help as I am having a trouble on how may I prompt a htpasswd in my WordPress project when user is Opening a PDF in my custom post type.

What I have done so far is to redirect the user to WordPress login page when a not Login User is accessing a PDF from a post in the Front-page.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(pdf|zip)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I am a beginner in WordPress and Htaccess so your help would be greatful for me. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could put all download files in a folder that is protected by htaccess/htpasswd, but is that what you want?

Comment: @flomei Thank you! I was able to solve it. I post my answer on How I solve it.

Comment: Glad you could figure it out and thanks for posting your solution, too. This will help others that come across this question and might face a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have now solved this issue, sorry for not mentioning I was trying to add authentication for the PDF viewing in my custom post, I have do it by changing the upload path of my custom post type and adding htaccess inside that folder, Thank you!